# Install Composer for windows on D drive

Tags: php, composer-php

So I have been using laravel on my testing laptop which happens to Linux. So installing composer was quite easy. I wanted to installed laravel on my desktop but when I went to install composer it auto sets its install path to `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`.

This is a very small solid state drive. I do not install anything onto this drive. Is there a way to change where composer is trying to install on a windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `--install-dir` flag via the **CLI** to point to where you want it installed.

From the docs:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin`

Comment: So I gotta use php to install the application to install my php framework. Does that sound backwards or is that just me? Thank you for the advice it is installing.